# How to setup efibootmgr when root / is an encrypted partition?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, uefi

Just wondering how to setup efibootmgr when root / is an encrypted partition. I'm installing archlinux on an encrypted root and their wiki says that i should use `# efibootmgr -d /dev/sdX -p Y -c -L "Arch Linux" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=/dev/sda2 rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img"` but what happens if /dev/sda2 is in fact an encrypted partition ? Should I keep it that way or should I specify `/dev/mapper/cryptroot` or other ?

Also how come that I don't have to specify that `vmlinuz-linux and initramfs-linux.img` are in /boot, does efibootmgr know that by default ?

Comment: The `efibootmgr` line is correct for an encrypted disk and, as long as your ESP is mounted at `/boot`, the boot manager will find your initrd and kernel...

Comment: @jasonwryan what do you mean ESP mounted at /boot, should I make an EFI folder in /boot and mount the ESP on it before doing the `efibootmgr` command ?

Comment: See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#EFI_System_Partition

Comment: Also see: [ArchWiki:dm-crypt configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration). Basicly you need to pass some kernel arguments (`cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:vg root=UUID=<uuid of the actual root as per blkid>`)

Comment: @cylgalad i did it but I have a big problem, i made a new thread maybe you know what's going on : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257478/adding-vmlinuz-to-efi-boot-adds-an-unbootable-japanese-caracter-to-the-boot-menu