# Adding vmlinuz to EFI boot adds an unbootable japanese caracter to the boot menu

Tags: arch-linux, boot, uefi

I'm trying to setup a boot on an encrypted partition so I enter this command :

```
efibootmgr -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -c -L "Arch Linux" -l /vmlinuz-linux -u "root=/dev/nvme0n1p6 rw initrd=/initramfs-linux.img cryptdevice=/dev/nvme0n1p6:cryptroot"
```

Unfortunately after rebooting all it does is to add a japanese caracter to the boot list and it is unbootable.

So here are some infos :

```
root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F9CA7213-905E-425E-AA19-3872C8801ADA

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    1128447   1126400   550M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1128448    1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1161216  758552575 757391360 361.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 760506368 1000214527 239708160 114.3G Linux filesystem

root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt
root@ubuntu:~# ls /mnt
initramfs-linux-fallback.img  initramfs-linux.img  vmlinuz-linux

root@ubuntu:~# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0000
Boot0000* Arch Linux    VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)r.o.o.t.=./.d.e.v./.n.v.m.e.0.n.1.p.6. .r.w. .i.n.i.t.r.d.=./.i.n.i.t.r.a.m.f.s.-.l.i.n.u.x...i.m.g. .c.r.y.p.t.d.e.v.i.c.e.=./.d.e.v./.n.v.m.e.0.n.1.p.6.:.c.r.y.p.t.r.o.o.t.
Boot0001* UEFI: VerbatimSTORE N GO 1100 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4294967286,0x800,0x1dd9000)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(2,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4294967186,0xac,0xf800)..BO
```

So what is this bug about, am I making a mistake in the `efibootmgr` command line or what ? I have to add that when I try to install debian I have the same problem (japanese unbootable caracter). Could it be that the motherboard is unable to boot on `vmlinuz` ?

Comment: Your `root=` is wrong, it should be the actual root, use `blkid` as root, copy the UUID and use `root=UUID=the root uuid`. PS: it's not a good idea to encrypt a SSD.

Comment: @cylgalad unfortunately using UUID didn't change anything

Comment: Then you should probably use systemd-boot, less problems anyway. See: [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#UEFI.2FGPT)

Comment: @cylgalad systemd makes a bootable entry in the menu but then the boot manager is unable to start arch linux (the only option is "boot to firmware")

Comment: Did you create the entry for Arch? See: [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot)

Comment: @cylgalad what do you mean entry for arch ? I did exactly what I described in my post. I also tried to install refind boot loader, same problem after making an entry for refind in the boot menu. I am however able to start refind and arch from the efi shell. All I need is to get to be able to boot refind or arch from the efi boot menu;